# hbase shell command : how to use the QualifierFilter

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Running the following commands in hbase shell, trying to get **QualifierFilter** working:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.QualifierFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.BinaryComparator
```

Got the **error** below:

```
hbase(main):011:0>  scan 'test', { FILTER => QualifierFilter.new(CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER, 'dummy')}
NoMethodError: undefined method `CompareOp' for Java::OrgApacheHadoopHbaseFilter::CompareFilter:Class
```

Can somebody share an example how hbase QualifierFilter works in bhase shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HBase console is `JRuby-based`, you must use `::` instead of `.` for statics reference.

Try that command :

```
hbase(main):011:0>  scan 'test', { FILTER => QualifierFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp::GREATER, 'dummy')}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
scan 'test', { FILTER => "QualifierFilter(>, 'regexstring:dummy*')" }
```

Take a look at [TestParseFilter.java](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-server/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/TestParseFilter.java) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for the exact column name, you could issue those 2 commands in the HBase shell :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.QualifierFilter
scan 'orgtable2', {FILTER => "QualifierFilter(=,'binary:lan')"}
```

wich will display only the `lan` column of the `orgtable2` table for the sole records containing this column.

More likely, you might want to display all columns of the rows for which `lan` column (of column family `cf1`) is present.  In this case use `DependantColumnFilter`:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.DependentColumnFilter
scan 'orgtable2', {FILTER => "DependentColumnFilter('cf1','lan')"}
```

If you also want to apply a criteria on the value associated with the `lan` column, then use the 5-argument signature:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.DependentColumnFilter
scan 'orgtable2', {FILTER => "DependentColumnFilter('cf1','lan',false,=,'binary:fre')"}
```

The previous scan will thus return all columns for the rows in which the 'lan' column is present and for which its associated value is equal to `fre`. The third argument is `dropDependentColumn` and would prevent the `lan` column to be displayed in the results if set to true. More details [here](https://karthkk.wordpress.com/2014/04/12/using-columnfilters-in-hbase-shell/).